# $\sum_{n=1}^N n\cdot n!$ as a function of $N$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, summation

$$\sum_{n=1}^N n\cdot n!$$

I have tried to find a common factor of the terms but the only thing in common of all operands is $2!$.

Comment: This series diverges.

Comment: Did you really just ask for the value of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty n\cdot n!$?  So... $1+4+18+96+600+\dots$?  If you keep adding bigger and bigger things, the result gets bigger and bigger, right?

Comment: I totally agree I don't want the sum's value but it's expression in function of n

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking for then, and from the way you are talking, I don't think you understand what you are asking for either...  Are you maybe asking for $\sum\limits_{n=1}^Nn\cdot n!$ written as a function of $N$?  If so, then why did you ever mention infinity in the first place?

Comment: im asking for the simplification of Σn×n!, n ∈ ℕ *. sorry for being imprecise

Comment: Your comment didn't make it any more precise, is what JMoravitz  said that you're looking for it as function of $N$?

Comment: yes here's the question as it is in the textbook , simplify for n ∈ ℕ* the expression : Σn×n!

Comment: forgive my impreciseness please , I am trying my best but I just did this fault of not clarifying my demand

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try [telescoping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series) with $n\cdot n!=(n+1)!-n!$.

Comment: will attempt now

Comment: I found that it's equal to (n+1)!-1 , is that right, thank you so much for the hint

Comment: another question : how do you manage to write such characters (like the one that you edited) in both the title and the body

Comment: @JalalEddine Correct, except that it's $(N+1)!-1$ (uppercase $N$, the bound of the sum). Regarding equations, MSE uses [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/), which means you can type in [LaTeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX). There are good guides on the web, just google it.

Comment: thank you so much, sir .